# Angular 6 : Dynamic baseUrl

Tags: angular

I am new to angular and tried to set baseurl dynamically based on environments. It should set baseurl to /dev/ in development mode and /prod/ in production mode.

I tried below code but didn't work and also not getting any proper error in console. I tried referring similar questions but nothing helped me.

```js
// environment.ts

export const environment = {
  production: false,
  baseUrl: '/dev/'
};


// environment.prod.ts

export const environment = {
  production: true,
  baseUrl: '/prod/'
};

// app.module.ts

providers: [
    { provide: APP_BASE_HREF, useValue: environment.baseUrl}
  ],
```

```js
// second code i Tried

// app.module.ts

export var baseURL = () => {
  if (environment.production) {
    return '/prod/';
  } else {
    return '/dev/';
  }
}

@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    AppComponent
  ],
  imports: [
    BrowserModule
  ],
  providers: [
    { provide: APP_BASE_HREF, useFactory: baseURL}
  ],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})
```

Comment: What do you mean by "it did not work" ? What's the problem you're observing ?

Comment: Are you invoking the config with the `--c` flag on your commands? like `ng build --c=production` aka `ng build --prod` and your environment.ts should generally stay default since the file overwrite's purpose is to replace it on build with environment.prod.ts, environment.dev.ts respectively.

Comment: Did you actually inject the service? should be something like this, "@Optional() @Inject(APP_BASE_HREF) private baseurl". Was it empty?